Error with stat_contour when plotting contour maps using ggplot2
I am trying to make a basic contour plot using 3 point stations using the base map of Mauritius.
I am getting this error:
Warning messages:
1: `stat_contour()`: Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 

My output map is as follows:

I am expecting to obtain a map with isolines like the one below. However, this map has been made on surfer.

My full code:
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(akima)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
mauritius <- world[world$name == "Mauritius", ]

# Convert the Mauritius data to a spatial object
mauritius_sf <- st_as_sf(mauritius)

# Load the station data

stations <- data.frame(
  lon = c(57.5, 57.6, 57.7),   
  lat = c(-20.1, -20.2, -20.3), 
  value = c(30, 15, 26)         
)

# Convert the station data to a spatial object
stations_sf <- st_as_sf(stations, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Interpolate the data using akima with a higher resolution

interp_data <- with(stations, interp(lon, lat, value, xo = seq(min(lon), max(lon), length.out = 500), yo = seq(min(lat), max(lat), length.out = 500)))

# Convert the interpolated data to a dataframe

interp_df <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = interp_data$x, y = interp_data$y), z = as.vector(interp_data$z))

# Remove missing and infinite values from the interpolated data

interp_df <- na.omit(interp_df)
interp_df <- interp_df[!is.infinite(interp_df$z), ]

# Check if the interpolated data is empty and plot using ggplot2

    if (nrow(interp_df) > 0) {
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = mauritius_sf, fill = "grey90", color = "black") + 
    geom_contour(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z), data = interp_df, bins = 10) +
    geom_point(data = as.data.frame(stations), aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red", 
    size = 3) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(57.3, 57.9), ylim = c(-20.55, -19.95), expand = FALSE) +
    labs(title = "Contour Plot over Mauritius Map", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")} 
else {
  print("No data available for contour plot.")
}


Hello, thank you for the reply. I have edited my question. I need to produce maps which is similar to surfer showing isolines.

I had issues with your reprex since the interpolation with akima package fails. In the help of the package akima::interp, it says:

x, y, and z must be the same length (execpt if x is a SpatialPointsDataFrame) and may contain no fewer than four points

So maybe that's the issue. I interpolated the data with terra and gstat using IDW approach (see more) and it seems to be ok.
See a reprex. In order to replicate your sample map I used geom_contour_filled but geom_contour should work as well:
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78
library(gstat)


world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
mauritius <- world[world$name == "Mauritius", ]

# Convert the Mauritius data to a spatial object
mauritius_sf <- st_as_sf(mauritius)

# Load the station data

stations <- data.frame(
  lon = c(57.5, 57.6, 57.7),   
  lat = c(-20.1, -20.2, -20.3), 
  value = c(30, 15, 26)         
)

# Convert the station data to a spatial object
stations_sf <- st_as_sf(stations, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)


# Interpolate the data using terra and gstat
r <- rast(mauritius)
# Finer grid, more cells (x3 times the initial rast)
r <- disagg(r, fact = 3)

# Interpolation
d <- stations_sf |> vect() |>  as.data.frame(geom = "xy")

gs <- gstat(formula=value~1, locations=~x+y, data=d, set = list(idp = 2))
idw <- interpolate(r, gs)
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]


idw <- idw$var1.pred

names(idw) <- "z"
plot(idw)



# Mask to land
idw <- mask(idw, mauritius_sf)


# Convert the interpolated data to a dataframe
interp_df <- as.data.frame(idw, xy = TRUE)

# Remove missing and infinite values from the interpolated data

interp_df <- na.omit(interp_df)
interp_df <- interp_df[!is.infinite(interp_df$z), ]

# Check if the interpolated data is empty and plot using ggplot2

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mauritius_sf, fill = "grey90", color = "black") + 
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z), data = interp_df, bins = 10, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_sf(data = stations_sf, color = "red", 
             size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(57.3, 57.9), ylim = c(-20.55, -19.95), expand = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Contour Plot over Mauritius Map", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")


Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the code. It was very helpful. I have tried to smoothen the data and including a shape file as boundary however, the southern part of the chart is blank. Is there any solution to extend the data to fill the missing part.

Try not running this line idw <- mask(idw, mauritius_sf)
